# I cant access any of my apache websites on my Offline LAN on my android phone

Tags: android, apache, wifi, lan

I've been trying to connect my Android phone to my Demilitarized LAN (LAN without an internet connection). It connects but I can't use any tools and services accessible on my router such as my Database server and Apache Web server. It has nothing to do with my router config. nor any of my server configs as I can access them both from my iPhone and Windows computers.

The problem: I connect my Android to my offline LAN through Wi-Fi, and suddenly I can't use my mobile data and I can't access my Apache sites (Located on my web server through the LAN) (And yes I do use the server's IP address in the search bar).

I've tried manually configuring the Wi-Fi settings such as the IP address, Gateway, DNS, etc. To access my webserver I have to enter the server's IP address manually into the search bar in Chrome but sadly this hasn't worked either. This is the same problem I had on my iPhone before I manually set the Wi-Fi connection settings which fixed it. One big difference between my Android and iPhone is I can't change the subnet mask on Android.

The expected results are as follows: Android should connect to the LAN network and allow me to access my web server using IP address while simultaneously allowing me to use mobile data (ie listening to youtube).

Comment: The expected results dont look like what you are asking in the subject of your post.

Comment: Funny, I thought I corrected that

Comment: They are still unequal. Your subject is different.

Comment: Do you mean with the "using mobile data" part?

Comment: There is not much more is it?